# After updating tensorflow-gpu, Why still use old version?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, anaconda

I update my tensorflow-gpu from 1.4.0 to 1.13.1 verion. But when i import tensorflow, it still use old version.
like:

```
common@Dell-7920:~/Brain$ python3 -c'import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__)'
1.4.0
common@Dell-7920:~/Brain$ pip3 list | grep tensor
tensorboard                        1.13.1
tensorflow-estimator               1.13.0
tensorflow-gpu                     1.13.1
tensorflow-tensorboard             0.4.0
```

pip3 shows only new version in system. But old version is imported.

update:

```
common@Dell-7920:~/Brain$ conda list| grep tensor
tensorflow-gpu            1.4.0                     <pip>
tensorflow-tensorboard    0.4.0                     <pip>
```

tensorflow version is old version in conda.

Answer (score 0):

Pip and Conda don't go well together. You either use Pip or Conda.

You should be able to update your tensorflow package with `conda update tensorflow-gpu`

Comment: Maybe because pip and conda can't work together. But most tutorials said using pip update.